# Discord.js mongoose connection failed

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

I was made discord bot with discord.js.
I was try to run this but it doesn't work.
this is connect to mongoose.
I am using MongoDB version 5.13.7, Discord.js version 13.1.0.
Does anybody know how to resolve this error?

And this is error code

```
Connection Disconnected!
C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:575
    return callback(new MongoParseError('Invalid connection string'));
                    ^

MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
    at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:575:21)
    at connect (C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:282:3)
    at C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:260:5
    at maybePromise (C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:692:3)
    at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:256:10)
    at C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:835:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:832:19)
    at C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
    at C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Users\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
    at Object.init (C:\Users\Users\Downloads\SkyHigh\structures\mongoose.js:16:9)
    at SkyHigh.start (C:\Users\Users\Downloads\SkyHigh\structures\SkyHigh.js:39:23)
```

And this is my source code

```
let { connect, Promise, connection } = require('mongoose');

module.exports = {
    init: () => {
        const dbOptions = {
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            autoIndex: false,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            family: 4,
            poolSize: 5,
            connectTimeoutMS: 10000
        };

        connect('', dbOptions);
        Promise = global.Promise;

        connection.on('connected', () => {
            console.log('Connected to MongoDB Successfully!');
        });

        connection.on('err', err => {
            console.error(`Error Occured From MongoDB: \n${err.message}`);
        });

        connection.on('disconnected', () => {
            console.warn('Connection Disconnected!');
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: It appears that you forgot to put the MongoDB connection URL in your `connect('', dbOptions)` call

Answer (score 1):

This problem has nothing to do with discord.js. It seems like you forgot to put connection URI in your `connect('', dbOptions)` call. You should put your local or atlas connection string to `connect('', dbOptions)` call.

**Example**

```
connect("mongodb://localhost:27020/mydb", dbOptions);
```